# Change Stylesheet via If in php

Tags: php, css, variables, stylesheet, if-statement

At the moment i'm trying to use a stylesheet which i get through a if. but it doesn't do anything.

here is my code at the moment. the variable $stylesheet will be variable but while testing i've setted it to normal

```
<?php
$stylesheet = 'normal'
if ($stylesheet = 'small')
    {
    $style = './sitestyle/stylesheetsmall.css';
    }

if ($stylesheet = 'big')
    {
    $style = './sitestyle/stylesheetbig.css';
    }
  else
    {
    $style = './sitestyle/stylesheet.css';
    }

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$style">';
?>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: the 2nd `if` needs to be an elseif, otherwise 'small' will never work, as it will be overwritten by the `else` in the 2nd `if` block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so as the others have said, `=` is assignation, `==` is comparision.

But your problem could be simplified by using a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
$stylesheet =  'normal';
switch($stylesheet) {
    case 'small':
        $style = './sitestyle/stylesheetsmall.css';
        break;
    case 'big':
        $style = './sitestyle/stylesheetbig.css';
        break;
    default:
        $style = './sitestyle/stylesheet.css';
        break;
}
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$style.'">';
```

Comment: +1 for the switch, but $style will never be in the output as you're using single quotes around the string that's echoed

Comment: thank you for this. with the echo output of scott it works perfect : )

Comment: To be fair I just copied and pasted the authors code, but you're right, the `$style` needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 6):

When comparing things, use `==` in stead of `=`.

$a=0;
   if( $a = 1 ) {
      echo "1";
   } else {
      echo "not 1";
   }

The `if( $a = 1 )` will use the return value of `$a=1` as a condition, in this case the return value is `$a`, which equals `1`.

Comment: To continue... if you use the `=` for comparison, it will always evaluate as `true` because you are testing to see if an assignment succeeded. Actually, if you tried something like `if ('test' = $test)...` that might evaluate as `false` because you can't assign to a constant.

Comment: ... And sometimes it's even better to use `===`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I'd forgotten all about `===`! Ok, who wants to define a `====` operator? you can never have too many `=`'s!  :P

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: "it will always evaluate as true because you are testing to see if an assignment succeeded.". You're not testing whether the assignment succeeded, but testing the value that was assigned. `($a = $b) === $b`;  `($a = $b) == true` only if `$b` happens to convert to bool `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Others have pointed out the problem with your if statements. You also have a problem with your echo statement. Variables will not be looked at within single quotes. You need to move the variable out of the quotes and concatenate, or change to double quotes and escape all your other double quotes. I prefer the first method:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $style . '">';
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using PHP's [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) instead of the [equals operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for your comparisons:

```
if ($stylesheet = 'big')
```

That code actually assigns the value 'big' to `$stylesheet` and the result of the assignment is then evaluated by the `if` as a boolean (this would be true in PHP).

You're going to want to change the `=` to `==` so that the expression is evaluated directly as a boolean instead of evaluating the result of the assignment:

```
if ($stylesheet == 'big')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch for this

```
switch ($size) {
    case 'small':
        # small css code...
        break;

    case 'big':
        # big css code...
        break;

    default:
        # default stylesheet code...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stylesheet =  'normal'
if($stylesheet == 'small')
{
$style = './sitestyle/stylesheetsmall.css';
}
if($stylesheet == 'big')
{
$style = "./sitestyle/stylesheetbig.css";
}
else
{
        $style = "./sitestyle/stylesheet.css";
}

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $style . '">';
```

one equals is for assigning thing in php == is for if it is equal to and === is for if it is exactly equal to

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a value is equal to another, use double equal sign `==`

$stylesheet **==** 'small'

Answer (score 0):

You could also forgo the switch/if entirely.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./sitestyle/stylesheet<?echo $style;?>.css">
```

Just make sure `$style` is only ever set to `""`, `"big"`, or `"small"`